# How can i know method started time

Tags: php

Now i am trying to benchmark for my application.

So I wrote a simple code.

Below is my code

```
$startTime = microtime();
$endTime = microtime();

print $endTime - $startTime
```

I don't think the way I'm doing it is efficient, so I want to improve.

I have to test several functions, but I think it would be too difficult to do so in the form of the following formats.

So now i try to  make a simple `Benchmark` class.

I can get the names of all the functions, but i can't get the start time.

```
public static function performance($_this) : array
   {
       $trace = debug_backtrace();

       $performanceData = [
           'Processing Time(ms): ' . ( microtime(true) - `{Method start time}` ),
           'Memory(MB)' . memory_get_usage() / 1000000,
           'CPU(%)' . sys_getloadavg()[0],
           'Call Function Name' .$trace[3]['function'],
           'Call Class Name' .$trace[3]['class']
       ];

       return $performanceData;
   }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered one of the solutions out there instead of doing it yourself?

The [Symfony Stopwatch](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/stopwatch.html) or [XDebug profiling](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

Comment: Thanks for your suggesstion.

Answer (score 0):

There was another way to use a different library, but I decided to use the class that I created.

Created `startedTime` variables in the parent class creator and added  microtime.

After this, I obtained the value of a child who was born and wanted to test the function `__destruct` Then I obtained the value.